# Why CO is a weak pi-acid ligand?

Tags: coordination-compounds, organometallic-compounds

This question was given by my chemistry professor, but I doubt that this question is not correct.

Following the lewis definition of the acid, any molecule or atom acts as a acid if it accepts an electron and according to *Inorganic Chemistry by Weller* CO is a good $\pi$ acceptor, then how it can be weak pi-acid ligand? In fact, CO is a poor $\sigma$ donor.

What am I missing?

Comment: Thing is there's no such thing as general scale of Lewis acid strength.

Comment: Considering $\ce{CO}$’s ability to stabilise low oxidation states e.g. in $\ce{[Fe(CO)4]^2-}$, I doubt the premise.